# Why is the debugger throwing "read access violation. this was nullptr" exception?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, nullptr

First time posting here, so sorry if this is a beginner's problem. I am trying to create a Snake class for a simple game I'm making but the debugger keeps throwing weird exceptions.

Every time I debug the program, it takes me into a 'vector' file, points me to a certain line and says: "read access violation.'this' was nullptr". When I run it without debugging it just terminates with the message: "exited with code -1073741819.".

I've been trying to solve this for hours but still have no idea what the problem is. Is there something wrong with my code, or does the problem not lie there? Thanks in advance!

In Snake.h:

```
#include <vector>

class Snake{
private:
    std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> body;
    int speed;
public:
    Snake();

    void draw_body(sf::RenderWindow& windowRef);
    void move(sf::RenderWindow& windowRef);

    void set_speed(int s);

};
```

In Snake.cpp: (I haven't finished Snake::move() yet)

```
#include "Snake.h"
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

Snake::Snake() : speed{ 10 }, body{ sf::RectangleShape { sf::Vector2f(50.f,50.f) } }{
    body.at(0).setPosition(50.f, 50.f);
}
void Snake::draw_body(sf::RenderWindow& windowRef) {
    for (sf::RectangleShape rect : body) {
        windowRef.draw(rect);
    }
}
void Snake::set_speed(int s) {
    speed = s;
}
void Snake::move(sf::RenderWindow& windowRef) {
    ;
}
```

In main.cpp:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include "Snake.h"
class Snake;

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "MY window", sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Titlebar);
    Snake* snake{};

    while (window.isOpen()) 
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {   
        }




        window.clear(sf::Color::White);

        snake->draw_body(window);

        window.display();




    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: Where else would the problem lie? As has been said below `snake` is a null pointer which you dereference.

Comment: @john As I said in the beginning, I had no idea what the problem was. Since the program ran without errors I was unsure if the problem was actually in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your code has undefined behavior (UB).  It can work by coincidence,  it can fail without any symptom,  or the weirdest things can happen.

The debugger takes in general extra care, adding a lot of controls.  And it fortunately spotted the use of a null pointer.  In fact, this line does not what you think it does:

```
Snake* snake{};
```

No `Snake` is created. `snake` is a pointer to `Snake`.  So you've just initialized a pointer.  What do you think its value is?

THe best option here is to get rid of the pointer:

```
Snake snake{};   // no *,  so now you have a real snake object ready to use

...
snake.draw_body(window);   // no ->  since it's no longer a pointer
```

Comment: Really? Why? Haven't I declared and implemented a no-args constructor?

Comment: @JensB always trust your debugger when it says something is wrong ;-) See edit for additional explanations.

Comment: there is also `body.at(0)` when `body` is empty

Comment: @idclev463035818 excellent! OP should really take care of this as well as soon as he has implemented the correction to the current problem (because his current code does not even invoke the constructor).

Comment: @bluedragon We agree that UB must be avoided because it means that the programme can fail. I have however worked with older compilers on older OS where by accident you could write something at address null, and read the same thing afterwards, so that the faulty code not only had no symptoms, but worse: it worked although it shouldn't.  So UB is really UB ;-)

Comment: @idclev463035818  I've just had a second look because of all these braces on the same line: `body.at(0)` is in fact in the constructor body.  The constructor body is guaranteed to be executed after the mem-initializer, so `body` is already initialized and is not empty since the initialization adds first `RectangleShape` on it.  Reproduction of a simplified case:  https://ideone.com/rjQlpy

Comment: oh sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Thanks! That did it!

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
Snake* snake{};
```

Does not initialize an instance of the Snake class, but a pointer to an instance. Pointers are integers at the assembly level and are initialized to 0 by default, the same numeric value as `NULL` in C and `nullptr` in modern C++ (these are all identical at the assembly level).

To fix this, you either need to allocate an instance of Snake on the heap with `new` and `delete` it when you're done using it or allocate the instance on the stack by removing the pointer.

Comment: "Pointers are integers at the assembly level and are initialized to 0 by default" - no. Pointers are not default initialized to 0 or `nullptr`. For example; `int* foo;` has a *indeterminate* value, not `nullptr`, and reading it is UB. In OPs code, the pointer is not uninitialized, it is *value initialized* due to the `{}` - that is what makes it `nullptr`.